# How to use strings as name to define a function?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, function

What I want:

I want to use string to be name of a function, I am defining. Code to reproduce result:

```
def creator(string):
    def string():
        return 0
    return string
```

So the creator function takes an input string, say 'test1' and the creator function should create a global function named test1. So whenever I call test1() (as a normal function call) it should return 0.

Comment: Why do you think you want to do this? Just do e.g. `string1 = creator()`, or use a dictionary mapping "names" to functions.

Comment: This definitely feels like an XY problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Try asking for what you're really trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Doubts whether you really need it aside, you cannot do this in Python.

What you are looking for is a way to set a global from local context. The way Python resolves variable names (scoping) doesn't allow to do so.